# can't add a nextcord slash command argument ( type error)

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

When i use nextcord and want toadd an arg too my slash command its says "Non-default argument follows default argument" and when I put None it works . [My code :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgpZA.jpg)

The error :

```
async def ping(interaction=Interaction, arg:str):
                                            ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

even when i copy the docs code i have the same prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you cannot have a default argument in front of a required argument in the function parameters. So when you set `None` as the default value for the `arg` argument, the error won't be raised.

Also, it seems like you're setting `discord.Interaction` class as the default value for the `interaction` argument. I think you want to make it a type hint, not a default value, so you can just change it a bit.

**Before**

```py
async def ping(interaction=Interaction, arg:str):
```

**After**

```py
async def ping(interaction: Interaction, arg: str):
```